# iOS App Rotation Causes Freeze

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, ios7

I have an iOS 7 application I am writing and when the app first launches if I rotate to landscape, then back to portrait the app becomes frozen/unresponsive. There are no error messages displayed or logs given. However, if I open/present a new view before rotation there are no problems when I come back to the root view and rotate to try to recreate the problem. The root view is in a navigation controller made in storyboard. I have no implementation of the methods to listen to or handle rotation events. The only things that occur when the app is opened is a REST API request is sent and the tableview is updated. Could this asynchronous call be throwing off my main UI thread? (I can post code as needed for the root view as needed.) The code being used for the API is from StackMob.com's SDK.

**Edit:**
I was able to recreate with iOS 6.1

Comment: ...maybe because of it is still just _beta_ and it is still under NDA?

Comment: Sorry, I should of clarified that I recreated on iOS 6

Comment: Are you by any chance updating your UI from within the async call which would run on another thread? And by updating UI I also mean something as simple like getting a UILabel's text property value. This might explain the issue.

Comment: I removed/added all code slowly from the async methods' callbacks. It appears the tableview refresh control is at fault of causing the hangout. I will test further as time permits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem with the refresh control by wrapping it in a conditional check. It appears I was hitting an edge case.

```
[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:purchaseFetch onSuccess:^(NSArray *results) {

    self.purchases = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:results];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.HUD hide:YES];
    if([self.refreshControl isRefreshing]){ //this check solved the freezing problems
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
} onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
    [self.HUD hide:YES];
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```